# New version of Google Chrome css display: flex issue

Tags: css, google-chrome, flexbox

After Google Chrome was updated, my issue started reproduce. The problem is that I can not set fixed height to child element (with so many children inside, that scroll appears) inside flex container. [`Here is code on jsfiddle`](https://jsfiddle.net/7560L27b/2/). By the way, setting min-height instead of height solve this problem.

Comment: Please review [ask] questions on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not the issue, the issue is the absolute positioning of `.tab-content`.
Here is a working fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/7560L27b/4/

Comment: Try to run jsfiddle in a new version of Google Chrome (43.0.2357.65)

Answer (score 0):

Use `flex-shrink: 0` for `.header`

https://jsfiddle.net/7560L27b/33/